# Socket server not accepting clients from other computers (connect failed: 10060)

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to use [this c socket class](http://www.mycplus.com/source-code/c-source-code/tcp-client-and-server/), but it only works when I use it on my own computer.

**Desktop only**

Server is started like this: `cSocketServer -p:2030 -i:192.168.178.22`

Client connects: `cSocketclient -p:2030 -s:192.168.178.22`

Works fine.

**Desktop server, laptop client**

Server: `cSocketServer -p:2030 -i:192.168.178.22`

Client: `cSocketclient -p:2030 -s:192.168.178.22`

Exact same as above, but this fires the `connect failed: 10060` error. Which essentially means it timed out.

**Desktop only (external address)**

Server: `cSocketServer -p:2030 -i:192.168.178.22`

Client: `cSocketclient -p:2030 -s:xx.xx.xx.xx`

Where *xx.xx.xx.xx* is my external ip address.

Same error: `connect failed: 10060`. Port 2030 is definitely open and accessible, because I tested it with a few unrelated applications that allow their users to choose their own ports (like utorrent). While those run, [whatismyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/) states port 2030 is open. But when I run *my* application it sais it Timed-out. Those applications do not have any special privileges in the firewall.

But even if I did mess up some firewall/router settings (which I'm fairly sure I didn't) that wouldn't explain why I can't connect to the server from within my local network. Other services (such as file sharing) work fine so there is definitely a connection between the 2 computers.

Both client and server run on windows 7 64-bit.

**Also**; for some reason, each client that connects gets their own inbound port assigned or something? Is that normal? When clients connect the server states;

```
Accepted client: 192.168.178.22:55156
Accepted client: 192.168.178.22:55164
Accepted client: 192.168.178.22:55176
```

What's that all about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two TCP connections have the same source IP, destination IP, source port, and destination port, there would be no way to tell them apart. To ensure they differ somewhere, clients typically assign a unique source port to every outbound connection they make.

As for the errors, you really need to do some troubleshooting. Do the listening sockets show up in a 'netstat'? Do you get the same problem with the firewalls turned off? Are the server and client on the same LAN (for the internal address case)? Is port forwarding enabled and working in the router (for the external address case)?

My bet is that the external address case won't work because you haven't configured the port to be forwarded by your router or your router doesn't support hairpin (local access to external IP). Other programs may work because they support UPnP or don't rely on hairpin (all access to external IPs come from outside your LAN).

I have no immediate explanation for why your desktop-to-laptop won't work inside your LAN. Are you sure both computers are in the same LAN? Can they `ping` each other?

Comment: The two computers are definitely in the same LAN and can ping each other just fine. Port forwarding in the router is properly set up and working for other applications, such as WAMP. Hairpin should not prevent whatismyip.org from seeing the port as open, but I tried connecting through a proxy to make sure and that had the same result. Netstat on the server does list 2030 as long as at least 1 client is connected. Firewalls turned off does not make a difference. This is quite weird.

Comment: You have something going wrong with your networking. Your desktop-desktop scenario shows the sockets themselves working correctly, it is the networking scenarios that are failing. Your router is either misconfigured or is plain broken. Try checking the router's logs for errors. You can also try using Wireshark to watch the TCP/IP traffic on your network to make sure packets are being routed correctly.

Comment: Wireshark (on the desktop) reports [this](http://i.imgur.com/HvrW0.png) while connecting laptop->desktop with LAN address. And [this](http://i.imgur.com/3OmbJ.png) when connecting to my external IP. Anything odd jump out at any of you? Also, each time when I connect externally wireshark sais `fuscript` or `resacommunity` instead of `x9-icue`. I think it's something different everytime.

Comment: The laptop was manually claiming a local IP address from the router rather than letting DHCP handle it, I disabled that and now that the laptop has been automatically assigned the IP address 192.168.178.19 everything is working fine, including external access. I don't understand this at all, is it possible that claiming an address manually screws up my router? Because that should not have been a problem, and certainly should not have affected my desktop computer at all.

Comment: It depends on the router. Some routers do not like it if a client assigns itself manually an IP address inside the router's DHCP range.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the -i argument to the server, or specify 0.0.0.0 and fix the code so that isn't considered an error, which is itself an error.

Comment: I specified 0.0.0.0 instead, but that didn't change anything. desktop->desktop is fine, laptop->desktop still times out.